# How to overload a statement to concatenate a string with a class object?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

My task is to attach a string to a class object.
I wrote the code - but it doesn't even compile, and it hardly works correctly.

If easier, for example. What I need:

```
int main() {
CString a ("first");
"second <-" + a;
a.Show ();
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
second <- first
```

The function I wrote (it should be friendly by the condition of the task):

```
friend CString operator +(char* str1, CString& str2) {
    CString temp;
    strcpy(temp.c, str1);
    strcpy(temp.c, str2);
    return temp;
}
```

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CString {
private: 
    char* c;
    int length;
    CString(int leng, char* payload) { 
        length = leng;
        c = payload;
    }
public:
    CString() {
        length = 0;
        c = new char[1];
        *c = 0;
    }
    CString(const char* s) { 
        length = strlen(s);
        c = new char[length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { c[i] = s[i]; }
        c[length] = '\0';
    }
    ~CString() {
        delete[] c;
    }
    CString operator +(const CString& b) {
        int newlength = length + b.length;
        char* newstr = new char[newlength + 1];
        strcpy(newstr, c);
        strcpy(newstr + length, b.c);
        return CString(newlength, newstr);
    }
    CString operator+(char* str) {
        CString temp;
        strcpy(temp.c, c);
        strcat(temp.c, c);
        return temp;
    }
    void Show(void) { cout << c << endl; }
    CString& operator =(const CString& obj) {
        delete[] c;
        length = obj.length;
        c = new char[length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++) { c[i] = obj.c[i]; }
        return *this;
    }
    CString operator =(char* str) {
        CString temp;
        strcpy(c, str);
        strcpy(temp.c, c);
        return temp;
    }
    friend CString operator +(char* str1, CString& str2);
};
friend CString operator +(char* str1, CString& str2) {
    CString temp;
    strcpy(temp.c, str1);
    strcpy(temp.c, str2);
    return temp;
}
int main() {
    CString a ("first");
    "second <-" + a;
    a.Show ();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is surprising (but even possible) that `"second <-" + a;` mutates `a`.

Comment: And how to solve this problem, in this case, do not tell?

Comment: Should it be `a = "second <-" + a;` instead?

Comment: @Jarod42, yes, it should be so.